# Hangfire not logging to NLog

Tags: nlog, hangfire

I have created a standalone reproduction of issue here: https://github.com/GuerrillaCoder/HangfireLoggingTest

Versions used:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.AspNetCore" Version="1.7.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.Console" Version="1.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.Core" Version="1.7.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.MemoryStorage.Core" Version="1.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="4.9.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

#### Issue:

Hangfire never writes anything to logs which makes it very difficult to debug issues with tasks stalling or failing.

I believe I have followed the instructions correctly and set LogLevel to Trace but nothing is written to logs apart from when I directly send message to the Nlog logger.

#### Step to reproduce

1. git clone https://github.com/GuerrillaCoder/HangfireLoggingTest
2. run project (observe that logs are created in LogOutput folder and message is written showing NLog is working)
3. Navigate to /hangfire and manually trigger task
4. Observe hangfire has not written any log messages at all

Comment: Remember to configure `NLog.config` in project so `Copy to Output Directory` equals `Copy if newer`. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Comment: That has been set.  Nlog is working correctly, hangfire is not logging to it.

Comment: But your example project doesn't have this configured. Care to update it on github?

Comment: Maybe you can try declaring Nlog in your program.cs, like this :
https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3#4-update-programcs

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the `ConfigureServices` like this:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Register NLog as LoggingProvider for Microsoft ILogger
    services.AddLogging(builder => {
       loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();
       loggingBuilder.AddNLog();
    });

    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    // Only needed for NetFramework with LibLog. NetCore uses Microsoft ILogger
    // GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseNLogLogProvider();

    services.AddHangfire((isp, config) =>
    {
        config.UseMemoryStorage();
        config.UseConsole(); // https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hangfire.Console/
    });
}
```

See also: https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/configuring-logging.html